# AWS Route53: how do I add a subdomain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, routes, amazon-elb, amazon-route53

I am very new to AWS and networking. I did the following, which worked perfectly:

1. Registered a domain name "**eyecloud.click**" on Route53
2. Created an ELB in **London region** and an ELB in **Sydney region**.
3. Created a **latency** route policy, so that Australia traffic will go to the **Sydney ELB**, while Europe traffic will go to the **London ELB**.

All working fine. See screenshot:[image]

Now, I would like to create a new routing, so that **sales**.eyecloud.click will always go to the **London ELB**. This is how I did it:

[image]

But it doesn't work. When I type "**http://sales.eyecloud.click/**" in my browser, I got following error message:

```
This site can’t be reached
sales.eyecloud.click’s server DNS address could not be found.
```

What went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on the TTL set for the overall domain, changes need time to propagate. Mostly root domains have TTL bigger than 12 hours.